# Uncaught TypeError: d3.select(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...).atrr is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having the subject error while plotting D3 graph. The data is getting loaded correctly because when I do console.log I can see the array.

Javascript:

```
d3.csv("../../shot_logs.csv", function (data) {

    var shots = d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .atrr("class", "shot")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x_coodinates + "," + d.y_coordinates + ")";
    });
    shots.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5);

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-main.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>D3 Charts</h1>
    <select id="selector"></select>
    <svg id="canvas" height="600px" width="1200px"></svg>

    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Error is saying everything you need to know. Console.log the object after append and see if there's really an attr function in that object

Comment: To much chaining makes it unreadable anyway

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo :)

Change

```
.atrr("class", "shot")
```

to

```
.attr("class", "shot")
```

Comment: Haha you have eyes of an eagle. Solved the problem. I wish I wasn't that stupid today :)